# code in atom showing different color in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am building a website using HTML and PHP.

just trying sample code below:

```html
<span align="justify"
  class="lead"
  style="color:red;">Our ability to address urgency makes us special</span></span>
<p align="justify"
   class="mb-20">Being the most renowned <b>event organizers in Hyderabad</b>, we understand it well that mood to make
some party doesn’t come with prior notices. It is the enthusiasm that transforms into happiness through the party at
that moment. And, once that moment passes, the enthusiasm level doesn’t remain the same.
We at booktheparty.in thoroughly understand the sudden exuberance to party hard well. </p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft"
 data-wow-duration="1s"
 data-wow-delay="0.6s">
<div class="pr-40">
    <h3 class="text-uppercase title">&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</h3>
    <div class="row"
         style="margin-top:-7px;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 mb-sm-20 wow fadeInUp"
             data-wow-duration="1s"
             data-wow-delay="0.5s">
            <br>
```

the original color when we type codes in the editor is like in the below image,
[image]

in one page its showing differently, i dnt know what went wrong
[image]

can anyone tell me what could be wrong or is it fine?

Comment: change your colour theme  :D Or may you missed close `html tag` Or missed `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you're missing a closing quote somewhere. This is because everything between quotes is orange, where as with the correct code, the orange part is before the quotes.

Try scrolling back up and seeing where it starts going green, that's where you're missing a quote.